# Samsung Galaxy S2 upgraded to Ice Cream Sandwich now Bluetooth headphones won't pair

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 which has just received the upgrade to Ice Cream Sandwich (I'm on T Mobile in the UK if that matters).

I have a set of bluetooth headphones. They worked fine before the upgrade, they would be detected by the phone and would pair with it without my having to enter a PIN code.

Since the upgrade to ICS, they no longer work. When I turn on Bluetooth, the phone detects the headphones but won't pair with them. When I try to pair them I get an error message that there is an incorrect PIN entered or an unknown PIN.

I know what the PIN is (0000). The problem is, the phone doesn't give me an option anywhere I can see to actually input this to allow the phone to pair with the headphones.

Samsung have advised me to do a factory reset of the phone, which I've done, but the problem remains. ICS is still on the phone and I still have the above problem.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Did you put the headphone in pairing mode before pairing to the phone?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The headphones are just or or off. I press the button on the headphones, a blue light flashes. At this point the phone can detect the headphones as a Bluetooth device. Prior to the upgrade I would then be able to pair the two, now I can't as I have described.

Comment: Which model of headphones? Any link or instruction manual?

Comment: Thanks to both of the above. I dug out the manual last night (didn't think I still had it). There IS a pairing mode to put the headphones in the first time you use them with the phone. I assume I must have done that when I first got the phone, but I have no recollection of it at all! All working fine now, so many thanks.

Comment: I had a similar bug with ICS 4.0.3. Seems to be fixed in 4.0.4.

Comment: Consider making your comment an answer, to have it accepted, so that future readers can find this as solution if faced with the same situation as you.

Answer (score 1):

[@Jules answered](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22496/samsung-galaxy-s2-upgraded-to-ice-cream-sandwich-now-bluetooth-headphones-wont#comment26285_22496) his own question:

> (...) There IS a pairing mode to put the headphones in the first time
>   you use them with the phone. I assume I must have done that when I
>   first got the phone, but I have no recollection of it at all! All
>   working fine now, so many thanks.